# Can we get paid through Paypal with paid android app as an app merchant?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm from Sri Lanka and I need to know whether I can use a PayPal account to get paid for my android apps distributions through Google play Store?

I tried Google merchant account but that is not possible to add my bank account details to it.
So i tried to go through Google wallet merchant account. But the Google wallet help center says that Google wallet does not support Sri Lanka

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Completely off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant. As far as i know  Paypal merchant service not available to Sri Lanka either, Even though you manage to use Paypal. Google developer agreement  clearly stated all the payment within apps should use  google merchant service.